# Lightning supports ES5?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I'd like to know if it is safe to use ES5 in Lightning. Is it fully supported? If no, which features are? Is it browser specific? Any predefined polyfills?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation for the new LockerService](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_code.htm), which is a non-optional critical update, mentions that

> JavaScript ES5 strict mode is implicitly enabled. You don't need to
>   specify "use strict" in your code. Enforcement includes declaration of
>   variables with the var keyword and other JavaScript coding best
>   practices. The libraries that your components use must also work in
>   strict mode.

Regarding browser limitations, it also mentions that

> IE11 doesn't support CSP (Content Security Policy), so we recommend using other supported
>   browsers for enhanced security.

As for your question about polyfills, they do not seem to be supported by the framework.  The Lightning Security docs say

> Do not overwrite native window or document functions. Do not attempt
>   to modify the runtime by including polyfill libraries.

in the section entitled "Additional Restrictions For JavaScript in Lightning Components".

Comment: For those brave enough to visit the source code one can get some hints. In https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/locker/LockerService.js you can see a list of ES5 & ES6 intrinsics that are passed directly through. In https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/locker/SecureElement.js you can see which element properties and functions are passed through and in https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/locker/SecureWindow.js you can see some more globals passed along.

Answer (score 0):

@minige this is an excellent question. the answer is yes, you should author your code in ES5, and the browser matrix that we target fully support ES5.

We don't support ES6 yet, but we do have some polyfills in place already, e.g.: `Promise`, `Object.assign()`, etc.

If you can open a case, we can probably document and formalize the list of polyfills that we use as part of the patching process for the runtime.